# Poi CellType format Cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've looked arround and have'nt found a answer to my problem.

I try to format a Cell with a custom CellType, does anyone know if it's possible.

I try to use the custom Format '[HH]:MM' on my Cells.

As far as I found out is it only possible to use the predefined CellTypes. Does anyone know more and can halp me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give some sample data T-Dog18

Comment: That format works for me.  What are you trying to format as? What's your problem, can you please clarify?

Comment: Those aren't `cell types` in Excel format speak, those are `cell formattings` on `cell styles`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of some code which will do what you are trying to achieve.

```
    Workbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = w.getCreationHelper();
    CellStyle cs = w.createCellStyle();
    cs.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:mm"));
    Sheet sheet = w.createSheet(String.valueOf("Format Test"));
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
    cell.setCellValue(new Date());
    File outFile = new File("Test.xlsx");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        w.write(fileOut);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // do something with exception data
    }
```